# Get the URL of the WebAccess for a TFS Team Project programmatically

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I want to get the URL of the web access Page for a specific TeamProject.

I found some samples using a TswaClientHyperlinkService object calling GetHomeUrl(new Uri("MyprojectName")), but I was not able to provide a correct Uri value for that. Maybe I did not understand how to format the parameter..

I know how to get the base url for the webaccess, but I want to get to the page for a specific Team Project within a specifc Team Project Collection.

Comment: @jessehouwing
Thanks for your answer, I have had the same idea, but id did not work for me. It causes an "Argument Exception: Malformed Artifact URI:https://mytfs/tfs/collection/project ". The URI is correct, so I do not get the idea.

Comment: Yes, the uri is complete and valid

Comment: Do you want to get the URL of the TeamProject site in SharePoint (`http://yourtfs:8080/tfs/ProjectCollection/Project`) or in WebAccess (e.g. `http://tfs:8080/tfs/web/Index.aspx?puri=vstfs%3A%2F%2F%2FClassification%2FTeamProject%2Fa33f88ab-839c-4ece-99e4-7fac491daed7`)? I expect that you are working with the API of TFS2010, right?

Comment: I need the WebAccess Url not the sharepoint, and yes, I'm working with TFS2010 API

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that the `GetHomeUrl` method expects a `vsts://` url, not the url to the project collection you'd normally use. The following code can be used to get the Uri:

```
 var server = TfsConfigurationServerFactory.GetConfigurationServer(new Uri("http://localhost:8080/tfs" /* your tfs uri here */));
 server.Authenticate();

 var service = server.GetService<TswaClientHyperlinkService>();
 var projectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://localhost:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"));
 var cssService = projectCollection.GetService<ICommonStructureService3>();
 var project = cssService.GetProjectFromName(/*YourProjectNameHere*/);

 var home = service.GetHomeUrl(new Uri(project.Uri));
```

Comment: Great answer, that works fine for me except for one little detail: 
For TFS2010 the interface ICommonStructureService4 is not available, it is for TFS2012. But ICommonStructureService3 works fine with TFS2012